# Question about my new workout routine

Tags: workout-routines

So I watched this video- 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rvs3-puHdEk&feature=youtu.be

This is freaking perfect for me!! I am 15 and will turn 16 on Sep 8. Almost 2 months ago i was REALLY skinny but then i started doing daily pushups. Now I do 200-100 daily. And my body right now is the one he had when he was 15. So I am gonna adopt this strategy.

So, my question is, I need some clarification about this. So, what he is saying is that we have to chose 2-3 exercises from every topic. Then do 4 sets of 8-12 reps of every one of those exercises everyday, 4 days of week?

And also I have a bit of extra fat on my stomach and I want a ripped body but you can't get ripped with extra fat..so should I run every morning without eating anything?

PS: This is my first post here so sorry if there is something wrong with this post or if this is not meant here. Also thanks for watching the video!

Comment: Generally speaking, it's better to post the workout routine instead of linking to the video. That way, if the video is removed, your question still has relevance, or if, like me, someone is sneaking on at work to answer a few questions, we can still answer even though YouTube is blocked :)

Comment: Because of your age, it is likely that just this workout will help you lean out as you continue to grow, provided that you eat decently (stay away from sugar). If you also run, and your body handles that without exhausting you, it will help as well. If your goal is to be muscular, sprints will benefit you more than lower intensity, longer runs.

Comment: oh so if i am correct..this exercise requires us to do around 400 reps a day?

Comment: Don't know how this ended up on the front page of questions, but I wonder if you had any progress @MartianCactus? :)